# Java SWT: Wrap main loop in exception handler?

Tags: java, swt

As you may know, the standard SWT main loop looks like this:

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
...
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
display.dispose();
```

Recently, I had an argument with a colleague about whether it would make sense to wrap the main loop in a try-catch, like so:

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
...
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  try {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
      display.sleep();
    }
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // TODO Implement exception handler
  }
}
display.dispose();
```

My colleague says doing it this way you won't have to immediately shut down the application if a crash in the GUI thread occurs, hence the user may have a chance to save his data before closing the program.

So, what do you think? Does it make sense to do such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a very good style to do so, because any Exception can occur in your GUI code. We have a generic BugReport sender at this location, and I love it, because nothing gets lost, and the app continues to work after the bug report (mostly ;) ).

Comment: Yes, definatedly very good style, but please notice that empty exception catches is very very bad thing. Because then exception is lost and debugging becomes a nightmare. I assume that you where really going the implement the catch. If you ever have to debug this kind of code, Eclipse has very good exception breakpoint handling where debugger breaks at any particular exception.

Comment: As I said... I handle the Exception, by logging it AND sending an semiautomated (user has to click "ok") bugreport for the exception to our issuetracker.